# C - Logical Compound Operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, compound-operator

Is the compound operator '&=' logical or bitwise AND ?

In other words, is `a &= b` the same as:

- `a = a & b`
- `a = a && b`

Comment: Why don't you run a sample and see for yourself? -1

Comment: Fair enough (+1 to comment above), but he may not have a build environment ready to go ATM. This seems a fair question to me.

Comment: Ok, But we have http://ideone.com/ ,http://codepad.org/ to name a few.

Comment: @axoim I was away from home, and didn't have access to a computer with an environment. school computers, ya know ...
I tried it out now, seems to work like &&, but its weird coz when I googled it, it says its bitwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a &= b` is using the bitwise AND operator. Think of the `+=` operation:

```
a += 5;
```

is the same as:

```
a = a + 5;
```

It's just a combination of two operations: `&` and `=`.

Comment: @effeffe - My point was just `&=` and `+=` are two operations put together, so why would the OP think `&=` should end up `= &&` anymore then `+=` would end up `++`

Comment: Because there is no binary operator `++`, while both `&` and `&&` exist and they are both binary operators.

Answer (score 2):

It's the bitwise AND, not the logical. (have to add some characters)

Answer (score 2):

In C, `a &= b` is `a = a & b`, i.e. bitwise. In C++, where there is a dedicated `bool` type, `&=` on booleans is boolean as well, as is a simple `&` on `bool`. None of these does exhibit the short-circuit behaviour of `&&`, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's `bitwise AND`simple

When you do `a&=b` It means `a=a&b`

Remember `a`and `b`should be `integral type`or promoted to integer type

While `&&` is `logical AND`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the queries that can be resolved through experimentation rather than interrogation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint8_t a = 0xFF;
    uint8_t b = 0x0F;

    a &= b;
    printf("a &= b : %02X\n",a);

    a = 0xFF;
    printf("a & b : %02X\n", a & b);
    printf("a && b: %02X\n", a && b);
}
```

Prints:

```
a &= b : 0F
a & b : 0F
a && b: 01
```

to the console.

Comment: Actually, it's best resolved by consulting an authoritative C reference manual, or checking the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  There are times where experimentation is the *wrong* approach (anything that invokes undefined behavior like `i = i++`, for example).

Comment: True - although adult learning theory would suggest an important role for learning _through_ experimentation.  In this case, reading the standard would seem the most prudent as you suggest.